# How to do a OWASP Dependency Check-Maven

Tags: java, maven

Im new with Maven and I have been told to develop a security analysis to it. I have read that the best way to check it is by a Dependency Check. Our teacher gave us a POM file that perfomns the analysis. However, If I check the report, I don´t see any error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVXGy.png).

Here is the POM file for the project:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TOP</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExpositoTOP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Exposito</name>
    <!--  FIXME change it to the project's website  -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.10</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>checkstyle</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.3</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>aggregate</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!--  lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom)  -->
            <plugins>
                <!--  clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle  -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--  default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging  -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!--  site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle  -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVXGy.png)
[image]

How should I edit the POM file so I can perform the checking?

Comment: So you have no vulnerabilities. What is the problem?

Comment: That our teacher gave us that code with vulnerabilities errors so we can fix it with maven, so it is suppose to be some.

Comment: But you only have junit as dependency. Maybe you need to add some more?

Comment: But why should I? Don´t get me wrong, Im don´t know what I could achieve by adding dependencies.

Comment: Your dependency check is only checking junit for vulnerabilities. So if there are not security risks in junit, then the report you get is fine. Maybe your teacher wanted you to check something else?